# How to disable Ctrl + P for Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

One of mine application having custom button to print the customer invoice bill. The browser also having default print option (<kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) to print the window content.

Initially, I resolved this problem by adding:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '80') { //cntrl + p
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
 });
```

But I feel, this is not feasible solution for this. because am here binding this (`keydown`) event on document. so on each and every key press on application it firing this (`keydown`) event, and so which is very critical as per as the performance concern.

Is there any other-solution for this, so that i could disable the <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (without binding event)?

**Note:** Important and good thing is our customer uses only Google Chrome browser to access this application.

Comment: By the way: `event.ctrlKey==true` is exactly the same as just  `event.ctrlKey` because this already returns `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, if some one have professional web based POS or business app, so for printing purpose you could use [JZebra](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) java applete, this would really resolve your all problems, because it doesn't have any dependencies on browser like print preview or browser's inbuild css etc..

Comment: buddy...great thanks..that's what we'hv implemented at our app..it's working great for some JZebra's receipt printer..thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is all about events, so you won't find a solution that doesn't rely on key events. Do you have actual performance issues? Every browser should be able to handle this.

Or, as a popular quote by [Don Knuth](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Ervin_Knuth) puts it:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Not exactly am facing big performance issues right now, but still my app already has huge business logic and various events at JavaScript side, And here adding one more (unnecessary) event on document level, this might affect an issue (performance) in near future..any ways thanks alot padde..

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using this instead:

`<link rel="alternate" media="print" href="alternativeUrlForPrint.ext" />`

Comment: Sorry, Am not getting this your point, could you please explore this?

Comment: Add this to the head of your page, replacing the herd with a herd that does the printing the way you want it. Then test in appropriate browsers and if it works you can remove any script

Comment: Cool! This is a very nice way to do it.